# how to match a string from a list of strings and ignoring regex special characters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this string:

```
d = {'col1': ['Digital Forms - how to spousal information on DF 2,0']}
```

I turned it into a dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

From this dataframe, I want to match this list of words:

```
wordlist = ['Digital Forms', 'how', 'spousal', 'DF 2.0']
```

I used the `findall` function with some regex to return my list:

```
words =  df['col1'].str.findall(r"\b("+'|'.join(wordlist)+r")\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This was the result:

```
[Digital Forms, how, spousal, DF 2,0]
```

I want to get rid of `DF 2,0` as it is not supposed to be part of the result. I know in regex the dot (.) is a special character used to match any character. In this case the dot in `DF 2.0` is used to match `DF 2,0`. I tried to modify my script and include something like `'\\.'`  to ignore the special character of the dot. Nothing worked for me.

Can someone help me modify the following so it ignores the special character of the dot?

```
'df['col1'].str.findall(r"\b("+'|'.join(wordlist)+r")\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may form a regex alternation from your word list using `re.escape` to escape the metacharacters:

```py
wordlist = ['Digital Forms', 'how', 'spousal', 'DF 2.0']
regex = r'\b(' + '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in wordlist]) + r')\b'
words = df['col1'].str.findall(regex, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```